# C# variables of class are zeroed after P/Invoke call

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, vulkan

I'm writing some vulkan code and ran into a problem which I can't get my head around. I've the following code:

NativeMethods.cs:

```cs
[DllImport("libvulkan.1.dylib", EntryPoint = "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(IntPtr vkPhysicalDevice, VkPhysicalDeviceProperties* properties);
```

GraphicsAdapter.cs:

```cs
    internal GraphicsAdapter(
        IntPtr deviceHandle,
        IntPtr surfaceHandle)
    {
        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties properties;
        NativeMethods.vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(deviceHandle, &properties);
        ...
    }
```

The Problem that I'm encountering is that the variables deviceHandle & surfaceHandle are reset to 0x0 after the P/Invoke call. Also if I'm declaring a List<string> with some values its null after the call.

I'm running this on a MacBook Air dotnet 6 & MoltenVK. Has anybody an explaination to why this is happening?

Edit 1: Thanks to the comment I found the issue. It was indeed what I would call a stackinbalance because the passed structure had a different memory layout than what was expected by vulkan.

Vulkan uses VkBool32 to express a boolean which is a uint32. I kindof thought since a normal bool is also 4 bytes I can just use it directly. Turns out its somehow not.. When changing it to a VkBool32 struct (which just have a uint32 value) it works again as expected!

Edit 2: A bool in C# is 1 byte not 4 bytes (like I suspected).

Comment: sounds like you properties structure is not laid out correctly - can we see it please

Comment: @pm100 Thanks! I've edited my entry post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you were able to find a solution to your issue please consider posting it as an answer so it is easily visible to others who might encounter similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment I found the issue. It was indeed what I would call a stackinbalance because the passed structure had a different memory layout than what was expected by vulkan.

Vulkan uses VkBool32 to express a boolean which is a uint32. I kindof thought since a normal bool is also 4 bytes I can just use it directly. Turns out its somehow not.. (its 1 byte on CLR) When changing it to a VkBool32 struct (which just have a uint32 value) it works again as expected!